# Async node file creation

Tags: node.js, file, asynchronous

I'm trying to check if a file exists, and if it doesn't, create the file.

```
self.checkFeedbackFile = function() {
        // attempt to read the file - if it does not exist, create the file
        var feedbackFile = fs.readFile('feedback.log', function (err, data) {
            console.log("Checking that the file exists.");
        });
        if (feedbackFile === undefined) {
            console.log("File does not exist. Creating a new file...");
        }
    }
```

I'm obviously very new to node.  Been working in Ruby for a while, and I only have a little bit of experience in Javascript, so the concept of callbacks and async execution is quite foreign to me.

Right now my console is returning the following:

```
File does not exist. Creating a new file...
Sat Sep 29 2018 12:59:12 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time): Node server started on 127.0.0.1:3333 ...
Checking that the file exists.
```

In addition to not being sure how to do this, what is the ELI5 explanation for why console logs are printing out of order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the `fs.readFile()` method is called. It waits for the io to complete. However, the `checkFeedbackFile()` method continues to the if statement.
Would recommend that you use [fs.stat](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_options_callback) to check if the file exists.
And [fs.writeFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) to write to the file a sync way.

```
self.checkFeedbackFile = function() {
        // attempt to read the file - if it does not exist, create the file
        fs.stat('feedback.log', function(err, data){
            if(err){
                console.log("File doesnt exist, creating a new file");
                //Do Something
                fs.writeFileSync('feedback.log',data);
            }
        }

    }
```

Node.js is asycn, if you are coming in from C or Java, you are used to the this:

```
function main(){
   1();
   2();
   3();
}
```

In C or Java the control will move to `2()` only when `1()` is finished. That is not the case with Node depending on what `1()` is doing, if its doing anything in an async way, say IO, then `2()` will be executed before `1()` completes, and hence you see async methods taking a callback, which will be executed once the relevant function completes.

Would recommend taking a look at how [Nodes Event loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) works.

Comment: Alright, I'll try it this way.  What is the benefit of doing something like writing a file synchronously vs. asynchronously?

Comment: So this is working, but the file isn't created right away, and I need it to be.  It's going to be eventually logging input as a read stream.

Comment: `fs.writeFileSync()` is going to wait for the file to be created. So on the line if you put in statements that read to or write to the file they shoudl work. However, if you have something after `fs.stat()` call, those statements may execute before the call back for fs.stat is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. In your main function you have two console.logs.

`console.log("Checking that the file exists.");` is inside a callback. e

But the

```
console.log("File does not exist. Creating a new file...");
```

is just within a if block. so it's fired first

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Sorry, that was a dumb question.  :P

Going to keep tinkering this and see if I can get it to create the file.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `console.log("Checking that the file exists.");` code is dependent of the call of the `readfile` function. you wrap it in the callback give as a second argument to the `readfile`. one the operation of reading the file is completed the callback will be triggered with the result. and all other code which are at the same level as the `readfile` function will be execute as if the `readfile` function have already finish it execution. the call of readfile will not block the execution of all other code that come after that because you have provide some callback which will be execute when the opration is completed.

This behavior is diferent of the behavior of synchronous programming.

```
console.log('first');
console.log('second');
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('third');
}, 2000);
console.log('Fourth');
```

In the code provide above in the synchronous programming the execution will go line after line. To log the `third` text. the execution will wait 2 seconds but in non blocking programming (asynchronous) the `Fourth` text will be print before the execution of the `console.log('third');`